# How to integrate wordpress as CMS for external website?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I have a site where i need to control the content by external site like, Wordpress or Joomla or drupal. HOw can i do it? Any suggestions are very much appreciated. If i edit it here, changes needs to be reflected in my external site..

Comment: Have you tried using feeds to display content from your WordPress installation? There should be an JSON API plugin available too, which allows you to fetch WP content.

Comment: Thanks for the updates on this. is this the one you are taking about? http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Comment: It seems that could work well, the description states they used that plugin to serve WP content with a RoR front-end.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should link the database of your CMS set up (e.g. your WordPress site) with your external site. Whenever you will do edit there, the changes will be reflected on the external site. But, first of all you should have written code in the external site to fetch data from your CMS database.

Obviously, just after linking to the CMS database, the required data will not be fetched and shown on your site. You will have to refer tables structure of the database and accordingly write queries and present it on your external site in the way you want.

Also, for instance your CMS is WordPress and external site is coded in PHP,
You'll need to use core PHP functions and DB queries as WordPress API functions won't work on your external site.